# Get the value of a listbox with a script in bash

Tags: html, linux, bash

I have this code :

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="test/html"; charset=UTF-8">
<title> CLUSTER GRAPH </title>
<h1> Cluster Graph </h1>
<hr size="4" color="blue">
</head>

<body>

<p> Choose a Cluster and press the button to generate the graph ! </p>

<form action="script_extract.sh">
        <select name="cluster" >
        <option value="Cluster_ALE01">CLUSTER 1</option>
        <option value="Cluster_AMR01">CLUSTER 1</option>
        </select>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Generate">
</form>

</body>
</head>
</html> '
```

Can you tell me how I can recuperate the value I have selected in my listbox to find her in a new pages ?

For exemple, I want a new tab will open ( I know how to do this without any problem) with for example the sentence

```
"Cluster chosen : *Cluster choose in my list box*
```

How I can create link between my first page, where I choose my Cluster, and and the page that opens and displays my sentence "Cluster choosen : *Cluster choose in my listbox" ?

Thanks you ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put method=GET in the form.

script_extract.sh need:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'

if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
        exit 0
else
        saveIFS=$IFS
        IFS='&'
        eval $QUERY_STRING
        IFS=$saveIFS
fi

echo "$cluster
```

PS: some configuration just accept just .cgi files. See httpd.conf or apache.conf